# Magento 1.9 - Why different Product URL for different Store

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, url-rewrite, store-view

I have 1 website, 2 stores, and 1500 products.
All products assigned to both stores.

Why every product has different URL for each store?

I tried to `truncate core_url_rewrite table` and re-index again. But still, each product has different URL for the store.

Ex:

Product = ABC (SKU = ABC)

Product URL in Store1: abc.html

Product URL in store2: abc-1.html

Answer (score 0):

The **url-key** attribute is configured to allow store specific values, It can live on a global `scope only`, `website` or `store specific`.

Try this:

1. `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Edit Attribute > Properties > Scope` = **Global**
2. Reindex ALL

For more informations [Fabrizio Branca explanation](http://fbrnc.net/blog/2013/04/whats-wrong-with-the-new-url-keys-in-magento)